# How to change reference of JSON which is copied in different object

Tags: javascript, json

```
function myFunction() {
var a = {};
a.myArray = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var b=a.myArray;
b.push("Chevy");
alert(a.myArray);}
```

In this above function I have created an object "a" and created an array "myArray". Now I am copying that array in "b" and modifying array "b".But why is it changing a.myArray and how to avoid this?

Comment: because you're copying a reference to a.myArray into b. You're not creating a new array from a.myArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you assigned the reference of that array. So you are actually referring the same array with different variable name.

If you want to seperate arrays

```
var b = a.slice();
```

Which gives you a new array with same values of your initial array.

[`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.